# Running ruby but `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, openssl

I ran the code:

```
./s-query --service http://localhost:3030/graph_v1_0/query 'SELECT * { graph ?g {?s ?p ?o . }}  limit 10'"，but it report 
"/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from ./s-query:24:in `<main>'
```

I have read some post about it, and tried

```
rvm reinstall 2.3.1p112 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

to fix it. But it report

```
Installing required packages: gawk, bison, libffi-dev, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, libsqlite3-dev, libyaml-dev, sqlite3, zlib1g-dev, libgmp-dev, libssl1.0-dev....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk bison libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev libsqlite3-dev libyaml-dev sqlite3 zlib1g-dev libgmp-dev libssl1.0-dev',
please read /home/zhangfanlong/.rvm/log/1679925322_ruby-2.3.1p112/package_install_gawk_bison_libffi-dev_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_libsqlite3-dev_libyaml-dev_sqlite3_zlib1g-dev_libgmp-dev_libssl1.0-dev.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Comment: I have to ask, why are you using Ruby 2.3 in 2023? Current version is 3.2

Comment: I am trying to run the code in "https://github.com/wala/graph4code/blob/master/docs/load_graph.md", and its requirement states that it needs ruby 2.3. So I have to use it without any other way.

Comment: Did you try running it without Ruby installed? There doesn't seem to be any Ruby code in that repo

Comment: I guess that maybe there are some Ruby code  in JENA or other components about it.  There would be no bug information until I ran the code about JENA.

Comment: I think you should give it a try and see what happens. The issue is most likely than Ruby 2.3.1 requires an older version of openssl, and brew installs the latest one. First I'd suggest you try without Ruby and if this doesn't work try installing a recent version.

Comment: Post the `.log` file